# Clear Pick an account in Azure AD after logout

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Once the user logout he still see all list of accounts which were recently logged in. Is there any way to clear the list and cache completely. I am using .Net core razor pages

Below is the screen he sees after logout. So i want page to appear without any recently logged in account

[image]

Comment: What does your request URL looks like? Especially the `prompt` query string parameter.

Comment: string uri = $"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd:Instance")}/{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd:TenantId")}" +
                $"/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}";

Comment: Sorry, I meant login URL.

Comment: Please try by appending `prompt= login` to your login URL. More on this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the session cookie of user information is still saved for your browser.As the Gaurav mentioned in the comment adding `prompt=login` in your login URL will always help in forcing the user to new login page without display of user information as it will clear the session cookie.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_eSe89gVW2DF1Dhj&Q_CHL=gl
>